# How to prevent dark mode inverting background images?

Tags: html, css, darkmode

I have a background image which gets inverted when a device is in dark-mode.

```css
#header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../../images/backgroundimage.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

When using:

```css
filter: invert(0);
```

It is not preventing the background image from getting inverted. Actually my whole webpage is already in dark colors. Could I force the dark mode to stop at all? If not, how can I prevent the image from getting inverted?

Comment: I'm scratching my head over this one @Linda but looking into it. As a side note you might be able to save yourself a lot of coding. Try this in your CSS... `background-image: url("../../images/backgroundimage.png") center center fixed;` instead of having 3 separate lines.

Comment: Once you wrap the filter around the body, you can as well add one for the images to roll it back. So, let's say you have an invert(1) value on the body, you can add the same filter for the images to give it back its original look.

Comment: I like your idea @AdemolaAdegbuyi however then it is always inverting even if a device is not on dark mode. Can I condition it on dark mode?

Comment: Use Media Queries

Comment: @Linda I assume you're only applying the filter in the first place when prefers-color-scheme is `dark`. So yeah, once you use the media feature, it'll only get applied when they set it to dark mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a background image then you should place it in an `::after` pseudo element and invert it the same amount of %.

```css
#header {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
    filter: invert(100%); 
}
#header::after {
    background-image: url("../../images/backgroundimage.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```